# Recursive function with delay in between calls

Tags: ios, swift

Using Swift 4.2

I'd like a function (`fetchReceipt` in the code below) to be executed recursively with a delay in between each run. The exit condition is when a run returned no errors. If any errors are encountered, delay before the next iteration.

```
    let fibonacciBackoffsInSeconds = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, 13.0]
    var receiptOk = false

    func fetchReceipt(notificationId: String, idLoaded: Bool) -> Void {
        if (self.receiptOk) {
            return
        }

        makeApiCall(notificationId: notificationId, idLoaded: idLoaded) { data, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // Something didn't work. Backoff and retry.
                self.receiptOk = false
                return
            }

            // process API response
            self.receiptOk = true
            self.processResponse(data: data, bestAttemptContent: self.bestAttemptContent!, contentHandler: contentHandler)
        }
    }

    for backoffInSeconds in fibonacciBackoffsInSeconds {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + backoffInSeconds, execute: {
            fetchReceipt(
                notificationId: ackId,
                idLoaded: idLoaded,
            )
        })
    }
```

The `asyncAfter` calls queue up **all** function calls, rather than sequencing the calls one after the other. Since `makeApiCall` can take a few seconds to run, `fetchReceipt` often gets called 2 or 3 times before `receiptOk` can get set to `true`... and even then, the remaining, delayed queued function calls still execute and return, which isn't ideal.

**Question**

How would this be refactored so that the calls to `fetchReceipt` only happen in sequence, and progress to the next iteration with a delay, only after the previous call has finished executing?

Is `sleep` an option here? I'm afraid of holding up the app's interactive thread.

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to schedule all calls at the start? Or, do you want it so that after the first failure, you wait 1 second then retry, after the second failure you wait 2 sec and then retry, etc.? These two options are definitely distinct given the time it takes to make the network request.

Comment: The latter. Not scheduling all at the start. After the first failure, wait 1 second then retry, after the second failure wait 2 sec and then retry, etc.

Comment: In that case does Kiril's post answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does! Accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't schedule them all in loop. Only schedule the next `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`, and preserve current attempt to know where you are in a sequence. I.e.:

```
var attempt = 0
...
guard let data = data, error == nil else {
    // Schedule repeat from here
    let backoffInSeconds = fibonacciBackoffsInSeconds[attempt]
    attempt += 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + backoffInSeconds
    ...
```

If you want to schedule everything at once, but then be able to cancel it, then you can't use DispatchQueue (as it's not cancellable). Use [OperationQueue](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5293-operation-and-operationqueue-tutorial-in-swift) instead.

Comment: So simple, and (now) so obvious. Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You need async framework like RxSwift to handle this job.
Tested and it works locally.

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import Rswift
import SwiftyJSON
import RxSwiftExt

// Not Important Just for better context understanding
struct Receipt :Jsonable{
    init(json: JSON) {

    }
}

// Important !!!
func fetchReceipt(notificationId: String, idLoaded: Bool) -> Observable<HttpResponse<Receipt>> {
    return Observable<HttpResponse<Receipt>>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in

        let DELAY = DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(0)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + DELAY, execute: {

            // 0.5 rate to simulate error or complete generate
            let number = arc4random() % 2
            if(number == 0){
                observer.onNext(HttpResponse<Receipt>(code: HttpCode.ok,
                                                   data: nil,
                                                   errorMessage: nil))
                observer.onCompleted()
            }else{
                observer.onError(NSError(domain: "domain", code: 1, userInfo: nil))
            }

        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

// fibonacci array represents for delays
let fibonacci = [0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]

// here we subscribe and retry fetchReceipt
fetchReceipt(notificationId: "notificationId",
             idLoaded: true)
    .retry(RepeatBehavior.customTimerDelayed(maxCount: (UInt)(fibonacci.count + 1), delayCalculator: { (index) -> DispatchTimeInterval in

    print("index == \(index-1)")
    let sec = (Int)(fibonacci[Int(index-1)])
    print("sec \(sec)")
    return DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(sec)
})).subscribe(onNext: { (receipt) in
    print("next value")
}, onError: { (error) in
    print("Error == \(error)")
}, onCompleted: {
    print("completed")
}) {
    print("disposable")
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```